# sp_executesql with a string from db

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, syntax

how can I retrieve a string (like 'select 1') from a record and pass it to sp_executesql to make it eval it?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

```
DECLARE @MySQL nvarchar(MAX)
SELECT @MySql = SqlColumn FROM MyTable WHERE MyId = 1
EXEC(@MySql)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here you go, using **sp_executeSQL**

```
DECLARE @MySQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @MySQL = 'select top 1 * from Information_schema.tables'
EXEC sp_executeSQL @MySQL
```

**EDIT:**
For a great read, that some refer to as the definitive guide on working with dynamic T-SQL refer to the article:

[The Curse and Blessings of Dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html)

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to Robin's answer. Important thing is to make sure you ensure you have protection against malicious SQL in the field - you don't say how the statement gets in to the db, but you need to be very careful not to allow bad SQL to get in there (e.g. don't want your data to be deleted by a rogue statement)!